# Use the value of a variable as a variable in html

Tags: jsp, jstl

Hi guys I am new to jsp and I am working on a project which need some jsp. I am trying to use the value inside the filesystem variable but can't find a way to. Is it possible or I am shooting in the dark?

```
<c:forEach var='filesystem' items="${requestScope.filesystems_ll}">
    <c:set var = "filesystem_var" scope = "session" value = "${filesystem}"/>
    <c:out value="${filesystem_var}"></c:out>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Whatever that is, it isn't HTML or JavaScript

Comment: this is not HTML but JSTL

Comment: Can you post code of servlet or controller , whatever you using?